# Webpack seems to be reloading my component twice with no apparent reason

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I think I am having a problem with hot-reloading in my app, both in dev and production mode.

Basically, I have an index.js file where I render an App component. In my App component, I simply console log "Hello from APP".
In my opinion, this should only be outputted once but it is not.
The output is as follows:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Hello from APP
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Hello from APP
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

The complete source code can be found here: https://github.com/RosarioAleCali/react-example

Can anyone indicate me what could cause this issue? Maybe my config file for webpack?

Also, this problem happens when I type the URL directly or refresh the page. I would love to fix it because in a more complicated example I need to make API requests and display data so the way it currently hot-loads is not good at all.

Comment: This will most likely only occur with Webpack hot module reloading in development. I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Comment: @Tholle, I am afraid that's not the problem. It still happens during production and for all the components

Comment: I see. Very interesting. Do you think you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: @Tholle, I don't think that is doable. At least for now. But what I can provide you with more code snippets here. I think this is a problem with my routes and I am trying a different approach to it. Do you have any good resources for routing?

Comment: @Tholle, hey can you take a look into my update. I think I found more clues

Comment: Very peculiar. I don't see what might be wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tholle, on a Redux community they are talking about some kind of hot reloading going on at the highest level. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Yes, that was my guess as well in my first comment: "Webpack hot module reloading in development.". Not sure why you get it in production though.

Comment: @Tholle, I just created a repository with a stripped down version of the problem. Take a look at it if you can. In my opinion the Web App should display "Hello from APP" only once but it does it twice. The link is in UPDATE 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this line in your index.html.

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

However, `html-webpack-plugin` will add another line that does the same, so you're running the entire app twice. You will want to remove that line.

The same goes for the (old) version of React you're loading in there, since React is already in the bundle.